# Smart contract not updated with Go and NewSimulatedBackend

Tags: mining, golang

I'm using the smart contract SimpleStorage and try to change the value with a Go script and NewSimulatedBackend to simulate the blockchain.

After deploying and execute the smart contract, the value doesn't change and is still 0.
What did I miss ?

simplestorage.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint storedData;

    function set(uint x) {
        storedData = x;
    }

    function get() constant returns (uint) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/big"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi/bind"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi/bind/backends"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
)

func main() {
    key, _ := crypto.GenerateKey()
    auth := bind.NewKeyedTransactor(key)

    alloc := make(core.GenesisAlloc)
    alloc[auth.From] = core.GenesisAccount{Balance: big.NewInt(133700000)}
    sim := backends.NewSimulatedBackend(alloc)

    // deploy contract
    addr, _, contract, err := DeploySimpleStorage(auth, sim)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not deploy contract: %v", err)
    }

    // interact with contract
    fmt.Printf("Contract deployed to %s\n", addr.String())

    fmt.Println("Mining...")
    sim.Commit()

    fmt.Println("Adding new value...")
    contract.Set(&bind.TransactOpts{
        From:     auth.From,
        Signer:   auth.Signer,
        GasLimit: big.NewInt(2381623),
        Value:    big.NewInt(10),
    }, big.NewInt(42))

    fmt.Println("Mining...")
    sim.Commit()

    info, _ := contract.Get(nil)
    fmt.Printf("Get data: %d\n", info)

    fmt.Println("Mining...")
    sim.Commit()

    // Get contract
    contract2, err := NewSimpleStorage(addr, sim)

    data2, _ := contract2.Get(nil)
    fmt.Printf("Get data 2: %d\n", data2)
}
```

Results

```
Contract deployed to 0xac3a4f57cd4686ddf90a882e29357034ff368a2e
Mining...
Adding new value...
Mining...
Get data: 0
Mining...
Get data 2: 0
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I've solved my problem replacing `Value:    big.NewInt(10)` by `Value:    big.NewInt(0)`

In

`contract.Set(&bind.TransactOpts{
            From:     auth.From,
            Signer:   auth.Signer,
            GasLimit: big.NewInt(2381623),
            Value:    big.NewInt(0),
        }, big.NewInt(42))`